# Azure Blob Starage - Rest API - 400 One of the request inputs is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, odata

I am trying to delete a blob from an Azure Blob Storage with a batch request.
At the moment I am using postman to verify my request before I use it in my application.
I cannot manage to get a different output or error. For authorization I use SAS.

Here is my request:
**Url:**
`https://APPLICATIONNAME.blob.core.windows.net/MYCONTAINER?restype=container&comp=batch&sig=SIGNATURE&sp=racwdl&sip=92.60.9.18&sv=2020-08-04&st=2022-04-27T08:52:29Z&spr=https&se=2022-05-30T16:52:29Z&sr=c`

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525
x-ms-version: 2020-08-04
```

**Body:**

```
--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 0

DELETE /MYCONTAINER/NAVIGATIONS.sql?sp=racwdl&sig=SIGNATURE&sip=92.60.9.18&sv=2020-08-04&st=2022-04-27T08:52:29Z&spr=https&se=2022-05-30T16:52:29Z&sr=c HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0

--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525--
```

**Response:**

```
--batchresponse_cdb19852-af76-4719-b9d2-8d61b5d3e6da
Content-Type: application/http

HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is not valid.
x-ms-error-code: InvalidInput
x-ms-request-id: 4dd49405-d01e-0035-12c4-601f12000000
x-ms-version: 2020-08-04
Content-Length: 221
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0

﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:4dd49405-d01e-0035-12c4-601f12000000
Time:2022-05-05T21:07:45.5349988Z</Message></Error>
--batchresponse_cdb19852-af76-4719-b9d2-8d61b5d3e6da--
```

I hope someone can give me a hint or solution.

Comment: @SrideviMachavarapu-MT that has no solution, only questions...